# Using Mockito to verify that an object is saved

Tags: java, unit-testing, comparative-review, mocks

We've been reviewing some legacy code and have found differences in the preferred approach to how to write tests using Mockito.

Both the following tests pass but which one is better and why?

```
@Test
public void verifyObjectSaved() throws PersistQueueException {
    final UserTokenVo userTokenVo = new UserTokenVo();

    String token = vodafoneSubscriptionService.processTokenRequest(userTokenVo);

    Mockito.verify(userTokenDao).savePayload(isA(String.class), eq(userTokenVo));

    assertTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(token));
}
```

and

```
@Test
public void verifyObjectSaved() throws PersistQueueException {
    final UserTokenVo userTokenVo = new UserTokenVo();

    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            return "completed";
        }
    }).when(userTokenDao).savePayload(any(String.class), eq(userTokenVo));

    String token = vodafoneSubscriptionService.processTokenRequest(userTokenVo);

    assertTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(token));

    verify(userTokenDao, times(1)).savePayload(any(String.class), eq(userTokenVo));
}
```

Here's the production code it tests — it's not very complicated:

```
public String processTokenRequest(UserTokenVo userTokenVo) {
    String token;

    try {
        token = new String(TokenFactory.getToken()); 
        if (token != null) {
            userTokenDao.savePayload(token, userTokenVo);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to save token");
        token = null;
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: There are actually problems with the code itself rather than the tests :p

Comment: @fge could you elaborate on that in an answer please?

Comment: @ferada well, I could, but wouldn't that be offtopic somewhat? Unless the OP wants it...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your production code, my positive test case would check the `getToken()` and `savePayload()` methods were invoked; and the same string returned from `getToken()` was also returned by `processTokenRequest()`.

Some points:

- I wouldn't use the any matcher with `verify()`. Explicitly state what you want.
- No need to return value from a method when you don't use the returned value i.e. `doAnswer` for `savePayload()` is unnecessary.
- As mentioned, `times(1)` is the default for `verify()` and used in your first test.
- Tests shouldn't throw exceptions.
- Static imports often make short code easy to read.
- Is `isNotBlank()` enough?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a combination of both would be best.

So first of all I'd favour less code, so `static` import all the things.

The `times(1)` is arguably good, I think the notes on the Mockito docs
were saying that it depends on whether you really want to make sure that
you only call it once, or whether you just want to test that "it
happened" at all. Also, as @fge said, `times(1)` is the default, so leave it out.

`any(String.class)` is better than `isA`, because it clarifies intent; since `String` is `final`, you can't get a subclass there, so `isA` is in a sense too broad.  Then again, `anyString` would be best, since it is shorter than the alternative and also checks for `null`.

The `doAnswer` is probably not necessary?  I mean *if* you return a
value, I'd probably check that it's passed through unharmed as well.  Also, I think usually you don't need `doAnswer`, but you can use a simpler way of returning the value; `doAnswer` would be needed for throwing exceptions etc.

Why do the tests have a `throws` clause though?

Comment: `times(1)` is actually the default, I believe

Comment: "any(String.class) is better than isA" Sure, but why? State your reason to OP.

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca thanks, I've added a clarification.